# Java MongoDB Passing Connection Parameter

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using Java with MongoDB trying to pass connection parameter from textfield like hostname ,port etc.What i have done so far listed below.My question is how to pass those parameter.Is there any tutorial or any suggestion?
Thank you in advance for your answer.
Please note that iam able to hard-coded connect to MongoDb so what i need is actual a user to be able to add connection parameters.
Thank you in advance for your answer

```
if("".equals(Server.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Server is missing!");
            }
     else if("".equals(port.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Port is missing!");
        }
     else if("".equals(DB.getText())){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"DB is missing!");
        }
     else{  
          String srv=Server.getText();
          String prt=port.getText();
          String db=DB.getText();
       try {
       Mongo mongo=new Mongo();
```

Comment: Use [`MongoClient`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) -  `Mongo` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: The question has to do how to parse the info dynamical with Mongoclient().